# Extending time of query element in view using animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation

The setup:

- A document has several checkboxes
- An off-screen div is collecting the changes made to the checkboxes
- This div will slide into view for x seconds after changing a box
- The div will (should) remain in view for x seconds after checking another (**resetting** time before hide)

I have tried variations of queue count `$('.hidden').queue('fx')` and position (shown below), but have not found the correct result.

The box does animate in and out. Two undesired things are happening. If the div is in view, checking another box makes it animate left with the remaining time of the first check and later, the box will never show & hide.

Apparently, I am missing some key. Please help me learn what is missing.

[Working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dcc/NgZwW/)

Currently using:

```
$('.futpur,.nowpur').click(function () {
    // In order to stop the queuing events of multiple selections
    if (hidden.queue('fx').length)
        hidden.stop(true,true);

    // If hidden, show
    if (hidden.position().left < -4)
       hidden.delay(1000)
             .animate({"left":"-4px"}, 1000)    // fully in view
             .addClass("visible")
             .delay(5000)
             .animate({"left":"-260px"}, 1000)  // hidden off left side
             .removeClass("visible");
    // otherwise, delay the hiding
    else
        hidden.delay(5000)
              .animate({"left":"-260px"}, 1000)
              .removeClass("visible");
});
```